# Obtener una fila por cada ID de una consulta según el ultimo código de la tabla hija relacionada

Tags: sql, db2

Tengo una consulta que deseo me retorne una única fila de acuerdo a codeRecurrence.
Esta es la consulta.

```
SELECT CODERECURRENCY, CODEDCURRENCYDETAILS, STATUSGENERALVALUE, PROCESSDATE, TRANSACTIONDATE, CONTRACTIDENTIFIER,
DESCRIPCIONARTICULO, NUMBERDOCUMENTCLIENT, CUSTOMERNAME,
VALUE, BUSINESSTYPEVALUE, TYPERECURRENCYDETAILSVALUE, CAUSALTYPE, CAUSALVALUE, NOMBRECATALOGOVALOR, SEQNUM
FROM(
    SELECT REC.CODERECURRENCY, RDET.CODEDCURRENCYDETAILS, REC.STATUSGENERALVALUE, REC.PROCESSDATE, RDET.TRANSACTIONDATE, SUB.CONTRACTIDENTIFIER,
ART.DESCRIPCIONARTICULO, SUB.NUMBERDOCUMENTCLIENT, SUB.CUSTOMERNAME, SUB.INVOICEDATACODE,
REC.VALUE, PROD.BUSINESSTYPEVALUE, RDET.TYPERECURRENCYDETAILSVALUE, RDET.CAUSALTYPE, RDET.CAUSALVALUE, CAT.NOMBRECATALOGOVALOR, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY REC.CODERECURRENCY) AS SEQNUM
FROM SCTMBTRECURRENCY REC, SCTMBTRECURRENCYDETAILS RDET, SCTMBTSUBSCRIPTION SUB, SCTMBTSUBSCRIPTIONPRODUCT PROD, 
SCSPETARTICULO ART, SSPCOTCATALOGOVALOR CAT
WHERE REC.CODERECURRENCY = RDET.CODERECURRENCY 
AND REC.CODESUSCRIPTION = SUB.CODESUSCRIPTION 
AND REC.CODESUBSCRIPTIONPRODUCT = PROD.CODESUBSCRIPTIONPRODUCT 
AND ART.CODIGOARTICULO = PROD.PRODUCTCODE
AND RDET.CAUSALTYPE = CAT.CODIGOCATALOGOTIPO
AND RDET.CAUSALVALUE  = CAT.CODIGOCATALOGOVALOR
AND REC.STATUSGENERALVALUE NOT IN ('FIN','FOB','SCU')
AND RDET.STATUSCURRENCYDETAILSVALUE != 0
AND REC.ORIGINRECURRENCEVALUE = 'INT'
ORDER BY REC.CODERECURRENCY DESC, RDET.CODEDCURRENCYDETAILS DESC
)
WHERE SEQNUM = 1
ORDER BY TRANSACTIONDATE DESC, CODERECURRENCY DESC
```

Al correr el select interno me devuelve la lista ordenada de manera descendente, haciendo que **ROW_NUMBER** se posicione de tal manera que el valor de **SEQNUM** gana el valor de 1 que serviría para comparar después, pero al correr la consulta exterior cambia de posición haciendo que el valor 1 pase a ser 3, haciendo que no me sea de utilidad ya que necesito el ultimo valor insertado según la tabla hija. muestro los datos a continuación.

Consulta Interior.

```
CODERECURRENCY|CODEDCURRENCYDETAILS|STATUSGENERALVALUE|PROCESSDATE        |TRANSACTIONDATE    |SEQNUM|
--------------|--------------------|------------------|-------------------|-------------------|------|
         16202|               14510|ERR               |2020-10-23 12:08:26|2020-11-27 16:53:57|     1|
         16202|               14094|ERR               |2020-10-23 12:08:26|2020-10-23 12:08:47|     2|
         16202|               14093|ERR               |2020-10-23 12:08:26|2020-10-23 12:08:41|     3|
         16201|               14088|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:53:43|     1|
         16201|               14087|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:53:37|     2|
         16201|               14083|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:53:15|     3|
         16201|               14082|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:53:09|     4|
         16201|               14078|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:52:47|     5|
         16201|               14077|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:52:41|     6|
         16201|               14073|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:52:19|     7|
         16201|               14072|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:52:13|     8|
         16123|               13675|ERR               |2020-10-01 17:06:17|2020-10-01 17:06:28|     1|
         16050|               13511|ERR               |2020-09-21 14:11:31|2020-09-21 14:11:31|     1|
         16043|               13470|EXR               |2020-09-16 10:04:20|2020-09-16 10:07:00|     1|
         16031|               13411|ERR               |2020-09-14 16:16:15|2020-09-15 16:16:29|     1|
         15467|               11872|ERR               |2020-09-01 14:52:23|2020-09-01 14:52:23|     1|
```

Consulta General sin **WHERE SEQNUM = 1**

```
CODERECURRENCY|CODEDCURRENCYDETAILS|STATUSGENERALVALUE|PROCESSDATE        |TRANSACTIONDATE    |SEQNUM|
--------------|--------------------|------------------|-------------------|-------------------|------|
         16202|               14510|ERR               |2020-10-23 12:08:26|2020-11-27 16:53:57|     3|
         16202|               14094|ERR               |2020-10-23 12:08:26|2020-10-23 12:08:47|     2|
         16202|               14093|ERR               |2020-10-23 12:08:26|2020-10-23 12:08:41|     1|
         16201|               14088|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:53:43|     8|
         16201|               14087|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:53:37|     7|
         16201|               14083|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:53:15|     6|
         16201|               14082|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:53:09|     5|
         16201|               14078|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:52:47|     4|
         16201|               14077|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:52:41|     3|
         16201|               14073|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:52:19|     2|
         16201|               14072|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:52:13|     1|
         16123|               13675|ERR               |2020-10-01 17:06:17|2020-10-01 17:06:28|     1|
         16050|               13511|ERR               |2020-09-21 14:11:31|2020-09-21 14:11:31|     1|
         16043|               13470|EXR               |2020-09-16 10:04:20|2020-09-16 10:07:00|     1|
         16031|               13411|ERR               |2020-09-14 16:16:15|2020-09-15 16:16:29|     1|
         15467|               11872|ERR               |2020-09-01 14:52:23|2020-09-01 14:52:23|     1|
```

Consulta usando **SEQNUM**

```
ODERECURRENCY|CODEDCURRENCYDETAILS|STATUSGENERALVALUE|PROCESSDATE        |TRANSACTIONDATE    |SEQNUM
-------------|--------------------|------------------|-------------------|-------------------|------
        16202|               14093|ERR               |2020-10-23 12:08:26|2020-10-23 12:08:41|     1
        16201|               14072|EXR               |2020-10-22 23:51:58|2020-10-22 23:52:13|     1
        16123|               13675|ERR               |2020-10-01 17:06:17|2020-10-01 17:06:28|     1
        16050|               13511|ERR               |2020-09-21 14:11:31|2020-09-21 14:11:31|     1
        16043|               13470|EXR               |2020-09-16 10:04:20|2020-09-16 10:07:00|     1
        16031|               13411|ERR               |2020-09-14 16:16:15|2020-09-15 16:16:29|     1
        15467|               11872|ERR               |2020-09-01 14:52:23|2020-09-01 14:52:23|     1
        14891|                9665|EXR               |2020-08-25 10:19:16|2020-08-25 10:20:20|     1
        14744|                8449|ERR               |2020-08-11 15:27:24|2020-08-11 15:27:26|     1
        14659|                8192|ERR               |2020-07-16 17:28:18|2020-07-16 17:28:27|     1
        14580|                8028|ERR               |2020-07-09 09:03:34|2020-07-09 09:03:36|     1
        14570|                8008|ERR               |2020-06-29 14:07:09|2020-06-29 14:07:12|     1
        14559|                7970|PEN               |2020-06-26 16:32:35|2020-06-26 16:32:13|     1
```

Como puedo evitar que cambie el orden al correr toda la consulta. Uso el motor DB2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final agregue una nueva lineal
**ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY REC.CODERECURRENCY DESC, RDET.CODEDCURRENCYDETAILS DESC) AS ORGANIZE**
Esta linea me ayudo a guardar el orden necesario, al final de la consulta utilizo otro order by para obtener los datos ordenados.

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT REC.CODERECURRENCY, RDET.CODEDCURRENCYDETAILS, REC.
    STATUSGENERALTYPE, REC.STATUSGENERALVALUE, REC.COMPANYCODE, PROD.COMPANYVALUE, PROD.SERVICEVALUE,
    REC.PROCESSDATE, RDET.TRANSACTIONDATE, SUB.CONTRACTIDENTIFIER,
    PROD.PRODUCTCODE, SUB.NUMBERDOCUMENTCLIENT, SUB.CUSTOMERNAME,
    SUB.SUSCRIPTIONVALUE, SUB.STATUSSUBSCRIPTIONVALUE, REC.ORIGINRECURRENCEVALUE, 
    REC.VALUE, REC.STATUS, PROD.BUSINESSTYPETYPE, PROD.BUSINESSTYPEVALUE,
    RDET.TYPERECURRENCYDETAILSTYPE, RDET.TYPERECURRENCYDETAILSVALUE,
    RDET.CAUSALTYPE, RDET.CAUSALVALUE, CAT.NOMBRECATALOGOVALOR, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY REC.CODERECURRENCY DESC, RDET.CODEDCURRENCYDETAILS DESC) AS ORGANIZE,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY REC.CODERECURRENCY) AS SEQNUM
    FROM SCTMBTRECURRENCY REC, SCTMBTRECURRENCYDETAILS RDET, SCTMBTSUBSCRIPTION SUB, SCTMBTSUBSCRIPTIONPRODUCT PROD, 
    SCSPETARTICULO ART, SSPCOTCATALOGOVALOR CAT
    WHERE REC.CODERECURRENCY = RDET.CODERECURRENCY 
    AND REC.CODESUSCRIPTION = SUB.CODESUSCRIPTION 
    AND REC.CODESUBSCRIPTIONPRODUCT = PROD.CODESUBSCRIPTIONPRODUCT 
    AND ART.CODIGOARTICULO = PROD.PRODUCTCODE
    AND RDET.CAUSALTYPE = CAT.CODIGOCATALOGOTIPO
    AND RDET.CAUSALVALUE  = CAT.CODIGOCATALOGOVALOR
    AND REC.STATUSGENERALVALUE NOT IN ('FIN','FOB','SCU')
    AND RDET.STATUSCURRENCYDETAILSVALUE != 0
    AND REC.ORIGINRECURRENCEVALUE = 'INT'
)
WHERE SEQNUM = 1
ORDER BY CODERECURRENCY DESC, CODEDCURRENCYDETAILS DESC
;
```